# One second after projection, a stone moves at an angle 45 with the horizontal. Two seconds after projection

Tags: kinematics

It moves horizontally. It’s angle of projection is

MY SOLUTION

Time of flight is 4sec

Therefore $usin\theta=20$

Also after 2 sec, the vertical velocity is zero

At one second, the vertical velocity is $\frac{u_0}{\sqrt 2}$

$$0=\frac{u_0}{\sqrt 2} - 10$$
$$u_0=10\sqrt 2$$
That’s as far as i could go, what should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity vector of the stone at a point with time $t\ge0$ after projection is
$$(u\cos{(\theta)},u\sin{(\theta)}-gt)$$
When $t=2$, the horizontal component is zero so
$$u\sin{(\theta)}-2g=0$$
$$\therefore u=\frac{2g}{\sin{(\theta)}}$$
When $t=1$ both the horizontal and vertical components are equal as they make a $45^\circ$ with the horizontal so
$$u\cos{(\theta)}=u\sin{(\theta)}-g$$
$$u\cos{(\theta)}=\left(\frac{2g}{\sin{(\theta)}}\right)\sin{(\theta)}-g$$
$$u\cos{(\theta)}=g$$
$$\therefore u=\frac{g}{\cos{(\theta)}}$$
Combining these equalities we get
$$\frac{2g}{\sin{(\theta)}}=\frac{g}{\cos{(\theta)}}$$
$$\sin{(\theta)}=2\cos{(\theta)}$$
$$\tan{(\theta)}=2$$
$$\therefore\theta=\arctan{(2)}$$